# VueJS - Axios array not updated

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to update from an API my array declared in data. When I init the array with an object, this object appears well in the HTML code. It seems that the array is not "saved" after the scope of the axios call. Anyone can help me please ? I don't have any error code/message.

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#recettes',
data: {
  results: []
},
created() {
  axios.get('url')
  .then((response) => {
    this.results = response.data
    console.log("Size before end of scope = " + this.results.length)  // = 4
  });
  console.log("Size after = " + this.results.length) // = 0
}
});
```

The response API is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "titre": "Cassoulet",
    "contenu": "Couper. Faire cuire...",
    "id_util": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "titre": "Gateau",
    "contenu": "chocolat",
    "id_util": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "titre": "Gateau",
    "contenu": "fraise",
    "id_util": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "titre": "Gateau",
    "contenu": "Mélanger, cuire, four 220°...",
    "id_util": 5
  }
]
```

Template:

```
    <div id="recettes">
    <div v-for="result in results">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-divider">
          {{ result.titre }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-section">
          {{ result.contenu }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#recettes',
  data: {
    results: []
},
created() {
  axios.get('URL')
  .then(response => {
    this.results = response.data
    console.log("size: " + this.results.length)
    console.log('results[0]: ' + this.results[0].titre)
  })
}
});
```

With this code, results[0].titre contains the right string. But in the HTML code, no cards are displayed.
And with this code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#recettes',
  data: {
    results: [
      {"id" = 1, "id":1,"titre":"Cassoulet","contenu":"Couper. Faire cuire...","id_util":1}
    ]
},
created() {
  axios.get('URL')
  .then(response => {
    this.results = response.data
    console.log("size: " + this.results.length)
    console.log('results[0]: ' + this.results[0].titre)
  })
}
});
```

One card is displayed in the HTML with titre = "Cassoulet" and contenu = "Couper. Faire cuire..."

It's why I said that it seems that the array is not updated...

Comment: What is your template?

Comment: I added the template

Comment: Is your template inside a div with an id = recettes? I don't see a problem in your code. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JJGGwy?editors=1010

Comment: Are you using laravel or something that uses `{{ }}` for interpolation?

Comment: It doesn't work in my app, "cards" are not created. No I just use Bootstrap

Comment: What version of Vue?

Comment: I think `this.$set(this,'results',response.data);` might help.

Comment: The result is updating fine. They're just confused about why the length is `0` "after" the `then` call.

Comment: @BillCriswell no, I think the problem is no "cards" are rendered, and I don't see a reason in anything posted that would explain that.

Comment: @BertEvans I disagree. "When I init the array with an object, this object appears well in the HTML code. It seems that the array is not "saved" after the scope of the axios call."

Comment: @BillCriswell I interpreted that as if he initializes `results` in data with actual data, the cards are rendered, but when he introduced the ajax call, it no longer renders.

Comment: The comments in the markup suggest they're not following that the async call takes time. Their code works perfectly fine according to that. Unless there's a lot more going on they're completely leaving out.

Comment: When they say "cards" maybe they're talking about the results array literally after the `.get()`?

Comment: Plus their comments all along the answers.

Comment: @BillCriswell Yeah, I'm not sure. Not enough info yet :)

Comment: @BillCriswell reading back through it all I can see your interpretation though and I might just be off on my own adventure.

Comment: The problem is that cards don't appear, unless I init the array (so results: [{object}]). In this case, one card is created and value of object are written in it. But after the axios call, the card is still here and the array is not updated.

Comment: I use the latest version of Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this is an async problem. As you can see, javascript doesn't wait for another for a function to finish. Try this one.

```
created() {
  axios.get('url')
  .then((response) => {
    this.results = response.data
    console.log("Size before end of scope = " + this.results.length)  // = 4
    return true;
  }).then((response) => {
      console.log("Size after = " + this.results.length) // = 4
  });
  // console.log("Size after = " + this.results.length) // = 0
}
```

**UPDATE1 : Added fiddle**

Here's a sample fiddle for you to look on.
https://jsfiddle.net/khenxi/n49zj258/

Comment: Thanks for your help. The result in "size after" is still 0

Comment: added a fiddle. check it out

Comment: Ok I go to check it

Answer (score 0):

Vue is reactive.

The request is async so the code where you're checking the size runs **before** the `then()` part. If you put `{{ results.length }}` in your template it'll be `0` then `4` very quickly, you'll likely never even see it at 0.

Just because the length is `0` when you log doesn't mean it's not "saved".

If you want the length in a variable you can use a computed property and do:

```
computed: {
  resultsLength () {
    return this.results.length
  },
}
```

Comment: Ok so it's normal for the length. But unfortunately my cards still not appear

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have the answer but this is my solution. You have to use the mounted lifecycle to update your array:

```
 data() {
    return {
      headings: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("url")
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.headings = result.data;
      });
  }
```

After the async call, the headings array will have the new values.

Answer (score 0):

**Three things** to keep in mind while **working with Vue**:

> 1. Use **Vue.set()** to assign values for reactive data members(**Arrays/Objects**)
> 2. Use **Computed properties** for reactive data members.
> 3. Use **Vue.$nexttick()** in mounted Function to ensure that the DOM is ready.
> 4. In your case you should use `Mounted hook` instead of Created hook.

```
import Vue from'vue'
...
mounted() {
    Vue.$nexttick(function(){
        axios
        .get('url')
        .then((response) => {

            Vue.set(this,'results',response.data)
            console.log("Size before end of scope = " + this.results.length)  // = 4
        });
        console.log("Size after = " + this.results.length) // = 0
    }
},
computed: {
    //Optional
    freshResults: function() {
        return this.results
    }
}
```

> Hope this helps. You may refer official docs for more information:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set